# polymer render elements before ajax complete

Tags: jquery, ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm playing around polymer those days, just to test some possibilities regarding AJAX Calls etc.

And due to the polymer nature, I'm facing some weird behavior because of a DOM/AJAX race condition.

Indeed, I've a custom element that use an ajax call to retrieve informations (JSON) against a remote service.

Here is the component:

Component template partners.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="partners.css" />
<dom-module id="playground-partners">

<template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{partners}}">
        <section class="partner">
            <img src="{{item.logo}}" alt="partners logo placeholder"/>
            <section class="punshline">{{item.punshline}}</section>
        </section>
    </template>
</template>
<script async type="text/javascript" src="partners.js"></script>
```

here is the component functions partners.js

```
Polymer({
    is: "playground-partners",

    properties: {
        citizenship: {
            type: String
        }
    },

    attached: function(){
        $.ajax({
            context: this,
            url: "http://api.randomuser.me/?results=4&nat="+this.citizenship,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                this.partners = [];
                for (var i = 0, len = data.results.length; i < len; i++) {
                    this.partners.push({
                        logo: data.results[i].user.picture.thumbnail,
                        punshline: data.results[i].user.name.first + " " + data.results[i].user.name.last
                    });
                    console.log(data.results[i].user.name.first);
                    console.log(this.partners[i]);
                }
                console.log(this.partners.length);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I don't know why, but if I'm only using 1 result element, the element correctly render and refresh as soon as it get the response however if I receive two or more object it render the element with the correct amount of template (which indicate that it find out that the `partners` array have expected elements, which is confirm by the console output).

I'm not sure how to ask for a DOM Element refresh on polymer.
If someone could help me, It would be wonderful.

you can have the UI here: [playground UI](http://playground-io.github.io/www/)

Comment: Can you please add the relevant code parts directly to your question instead of just linking to it. Links a prone to break whuch makes the question useless for future visitors.

Comment: I'll update using a gist of this code

Comment: A Gist still is a link.

Comment: Ok, I get it, I've update my issue according to the needs and add a little bit of explanation/context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why to use JQuery to do this? You're supposed to use the `iron-ajax` element to do ajax's calls. [Here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax) you can find documentation about it. 
Anyway, I think you have to do ajax calls asynchronously, as follows:

```
attached: function(){
   this.async(function(){
   //ajax call here
   },someTimeIfNeeded);
}
```

So, when you get the answer of ajax call, you should use `this.set('pathOfObject', value)` to notify array or object changes.

#### Edit

Using you element, I think you have to do as follows:

```
Polymer({
    is: "playground-partners",

    properties: {
        citizenship: {
            type: String
        },
        partners:{
            type: Array,
            value: function(){return [];}
        },
    },

    attached: function(){
      this.async(function(){  
        $.ajax({
            context: this,
            url: "http://api.randomuser.me/?results=4&nat="+this.citizenship,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                this.set("partners", data.results);
                /* I think that your object should be something like this
                  data:[{logo:"logoUrl", pushLineData:"pushLineData"},
                        {logo:"logoUrl2", pushLineData:"pushLineData2"}
                       ]
               */
            }
        });
      }); 
    },
});
```

Comment: Indeed, you're right, I should use iron-ajax but, as I do want to know how polymer is working etc, I use JQuery and additionally I didn't download the iron catalog. I thing that I missing some informations as I don't understand what to put at the 'pathOfObject' on the this.set function as I try partners[i].logo and it seems to be undefined.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! I'm OK with it for a single dataset result but indeed, I'm requesting between 4 and 10 000 result on the service, so I have to use a push or unshift function instead of the set one, so I can't really have your exemple.

And for informations, I don't handle the returned object, it result value is: https://randomuser.me/documentation#results so my object is rather:
data:{result[{user:{name:{first: blabla, last: mooore},location:{key: value, key: value}}}]}

Answer (score 1):

Your element has only a property `citizenship` but you bind to partners. If you want to data-bind you have to create proper properties. For Polymer to notice property value changes you also need to use Polymer API to update values like `this.set()`, `this.notifyPath()`,...

Comment: I've tested this solution with only one result and it works just fine as the element check for the partner properties which is created on successful call and then refreshed. I don't get why it's not refreshing as soon as I use more than one result set on the partner property.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so thank you very much to both of you Flavio and Günter!

I finally get it, but I add to slightly adapt your informations as I'm working with a large result set and not just one object.

For informations, here is the relevant code part:

```
attached: function(){
        this.async( function(){
            $.ajax({
                context: this,
                url: this.url+this.citizenship,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    sanitizedData = []
                    for (var i = 0, len = data.results.length; i < len; i++) {
                        sanitizedData.push({
                            logo: data.results[i].user.picture.thumbnail,
                            punshline: data.results[i].user.name.first + " " + data.results[i].user.name.last
                        });
                        console.log(sanitizedData);
                    }
                    this.set("partners", sanitizedData);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see, I had to use an intermediate array to be able to insert the whole for loop result on the empty partners array.

without this trick, only one object is set.

What I don't really understand is why when I use this code:

```
Polymer({
    is: "playground-partners",

    properties: {
        url: {
            type: String
        },
        citizenship: {
            type: String
        }
    },

    attached: function(){
        console.log(this.partners);
        this.async( function(){
            $.ajax({
                context: this,
                url: this.url+this.citizenship,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    this.partners = []
                    for (var i = 0, len = data.results.length; i < len; i++) {
                        this.partners.push({
                            logo: data.results[i].user.picture.thumbnail,
                            punshline: data.results[i].user.name.first + " " + data.results[i].user.name.last
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Polymer create correct amount of child nodes but empty.
If it create the nodes, it should be able to have the required informations has they're provided by the loop during the push() call.

Here is the result page:

[image: Polymer gets crazy :p]

Thanks a lot to you once again!

Comment: Maybe, you need to do using Polymer's push method, as follows: `this.push('partners', yourObjectCreated)`. This is the correct way to push data into arrays. [Here] (http://polymer.github.io/polymer/) you can find more information about polymer's methods.

Comment: [UPDATE] @FlavioOchoa Really, a BIG THANK YOU for your help, I do really better understand how I can manipulate a Polymer object now!!

hum... OK! Many thanks, I didn't understood that the polymer object did re-implement such primitives.

Why did they do that instead of just inherit them??

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer, you seems to be involved on Polymer or at least with Google JS related projects, do you now where I could push some input regarding the polymer documentation?